# How to get the pixel color on touch (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I have various `CAShapeLayers` that each have a distinctive colour, made like this:

```
    shape1.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 85/255.0, green: 176/255.0, blue: 112/255.0, alpha: 1.0).
    shape2.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 222/255.0, green: 171/255.0, blue: 66/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
```

Using a `touchesBegan` function, I want to determine whether a `CAShapeLayer` has been tapped, and which particular one it was, in order for a suitable action to occur. I know it is possible to use `hitTest` and `CGPathContainsPoint`, but I want use a different method. How do I compare the colour of the point tapped with the colour of the `CAShapeLayers`?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: First you have to find out on which CAShapeLayer the point is, with CGPathContainsPoint, and then ju check the color of that layer

Comment: Unfortunately my CAShapeLayers all have the same path (as they are all sectors of the same circle), meaning that  CGPathContainsPoint will not provide a unique CAShapeLayer. Is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

This method should work for finding out the pixel color of the touched point:

```
func colorAtPoint(point:CGPoint) -> UIColor
{
    var pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(4)

    var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
    var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y)

    shapeLayer.renderInContext(context)


    var color:UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(pixels[0])/255.0, green: CGFloat(pixels[1])/255.0, blue: CGFloat(pixels[2])/255.0, alpha: CGFloat(pixels[3])/255.0)

    pixels.dealloc(4)

    return color
}
```

Comment: Will this work for a `CAShapeLayer`'s `strokeColor` (not only `fillColor`)?

Comment: This should work fo any color on the screen, that is corrently visible.

Comment: And you would use a simple `if` statement to compare the two colours?